# Tcl function args: strings with spaces

Tags: string, tcl

I am facing a problem when using a tcl custom command (in a software package which has tcl embedded in it):

```
*Custom_Command MyObjectType $ObjectName
```

The problem is that, occasionally, the object's name variable i.e. ObjectName may get a string (including space) as the name of the object; e.g. if it is a file name "`My File.txt`"
In such cases the command simply gives an error that there exists no object with such name.

If I remove space manually from the value assigned to `ObjectName`  then the command works perfectly fine, however as soon as it encounters any string with a space the script terminates with an error, complaining that no object with this name exists. If I use the command: `puts $ObjectName`   the result is: `{My File.txt}`.

Kindly guide me about any method to handle this problem.

Comment: It sounds like it is not being consistent about whether the argument is a single value or a list. If that's the case, you're going to be stuck unless you can fix the library; it's really _broken_ right now. (Or find a way to only use arguments that where `$foo eq [list $foo]` is true; a very strict restriction.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to quote it?

```
Custom_Command MyObjectType "$ObjectName"
```

I hope that fixes the problem. If not, please let us know.

## Update

When you prints `$ObjectName` and gets `{My File.txt}`, it tells me `$ObjectName` is really a nested list: `{{My File.txt}}`. That means along the line, this variable was quoted twice. You can either go back to the quote and undo that, or work around (not recommended, I prefer fixing the problem than working around it):

```
set ObjectName [lindex $ObjectName 0]; # Work around: Remove the outer list
Custom_Command MyObjectType "$ObjectName"
```

Note that if the variable was not quoted twice, the work-around will fall apart: For example, if `$ObjectName` was not quoted twice and have the value `My File.txt`, the above will set `$ObjectName` to "My".

Comment: Yes I have tried this one as well, but unfortunately it didn't work, and `{$ObjectName}` also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add skip characters at the space.

Script : get.tcl

```
puts [lindex $argv 0]
puts [lindex $argv 1]
puts [lindex $argv 2]
```

Calling get.tcl

```
tclsh get.tcl Argument\ 1 Argument\ 2 Argument\ 3
```

Output:

```
Argument 1
Argument 2
Argument 3
```